# Why can I no longer open Synology shares on Sonoma?

Tags: smb, sonoma, cifs

Up until I upgraded from 12.x to 14.1 yesterday, I could do the following:

1. Open Finder
2. <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>
3. Type in `smb://IP-ADDRESS/SHARENAME`

Enter the name/password at the prompt, and I will be able to access the share.  Since I upgraded last night, I found I can no longer do this.  I get a long pause with no action the first time, or an instant seeming failure of the password on subsequent tries.

I can mount this share from other computers in the network without issue, Sonoma seems to be the key ingredient in this breakage.

I wanted to ask this question to make sure people are aware it isn't a Windows-specific issue. This looks like a Sonoma bug that some are saying 14.1 fixes.

Comment: Right now this rather seems to be a description of the current state of affairs in regard to SMB mounts. What exactly is your question here?

Comment: @nohillside I initially asked here, because I thought I might get a high quality answer, and the other existing question has some rambling answer that doesn't make sense about windows something or other.  In the course of editing my question, I saw other posts on other sites.  I elected to leave the question, but it could be closed.  No one will be asking this question after 14.2 comes out, so high search rank isn't really worth it.  Not a timeless question.